# how to show vales of a json file in HTML (Looped json format Object in Object)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an API and I want to print data from API into my HTML given in the script. in API I have Lopped array. At ${user.TestUrlTable} browser only shows [Object Object], but I want to get values in TestUrlTable Object, which has some other values like TestUrl, Result, and others.

1. Javascript code is working for main Objects like: IpAdd, PortNo, country, availability, LasteDateFound
2. But the Issue is to print vales of object "TestUrlTable" like: TestUrl, Result, LastTested.
3. These values Should be printed for a given IpAdd.

**API Data:**

```
[{
    "IpAdd": "1.10.227.44",
    "PortNo": "8080",
    "country": "Thailand",
    "availability": "Available",
    "LasteDateFound": "6/21/2020",
    "TestUrlTable": [{
        "id": 937,
        "TestUrl": "http://www.google.com",
        "Result": "Working",
        "LastTested": "2020-06-21T01:04:37.143"
      },

      {
        "id": 938,
        "TestUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
        "Result": "Working",
        "LastTested": "2020-06-21T01:05:19.14"
      },

      {
        "id": 939,
        "TestUrl": "https://www.w3schools.com",
        "Result": "Working",
        "LastTested": "2020-06-21T01:05:48.413"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "IpAdd": "102.164.248.113",
    "PortNo": "8080",
    "country": "Equatorial Guinea",
    "availability": "Available",
    "LasteDateFound": "6/21/2020",
    "TestUrlTable": [{
      "id": 940,
      "TestUrl": "http://www.google.com",
      "Result": "Working",
      "LastTested": "2020-06-21T01:05:49.693"
    }]
  },
  {
    "IpAdd": "103.122.74.146",
    "PortNo": "8080",
    "country": "Bangladesh - Dhaka",
    "availability": "Available",
    "LasteDateFound": "6/21/2020",
    "TestUrlTable": []
  }, {
    "IpAdd": "103.151.47.213",
    "PortNo": "8080",
    "country": "China",
    "availability": "Available",
    "LasteDateFound": "6/21/2020",
    "TestUrlTable": []
  }
]
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
      let users = [];
      const api_url = "http://someapi.com/api";
      async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
          console.log(data);

          for (user of data) {
              users.push(
            `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
              <div class="pricing-table">
                <div class="pricing-header">
                  <p><h3 style="color:white">${user.IpAdd}<h3></p>
                </div>

                <div class="pricing-list">
                  <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span>${user.LasteDateFound}</span></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span>${user.availability}</span></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-lock"></i><span>${user.PortNo}</span></li>

                    <li><i class="fa fa-mail"></i><span>${user.TestUrlTable}</span></li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>`
              );
        }
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = users.join("");
      }

      getData();
    </script>
```

**HTML File**

```
<body>
    <section id="pricing-table">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id = "AdjResultsDiv">
         <div class="pricing" id="results">

         </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Table Section End -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JSON.stringify() to convert object to string, check below example.

```
 <li><i class="fa fa-mail"></i><span>${JSON.stringify(user.TestUrlTable)}</span></li>
```

or you can loop through the TestUrlTable to create the list dynamically, check below example.

```
        for (user of data) {
          let temp = ``;
          if(user.IpAdd === "1.10.227.44"){
              for(item of user.TestUrlTable){
                  temp += `<li><i class="fa fa-mail"></i><span>${item.TestUrl}</span></li>`;
              }
          }
          
          users.push(
        `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
          <div class="pricing-table">
            <div class="pricing-header">
              <p><h3 style="color:white">${user.IpAdd}<h3></p>
            </div>

            <div class="pricing-list">
              <ul>
                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span>${user.LasteDateFound}</span></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span>${user.availability}</span></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-lock"></i><span>${user.PortNo}</span></li>

                ${temp}

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`
          );
    }
```

Comment: yes, i can get object from it, but for :

```
<li><i class="fa fa-mail"></i><span>${JSON.stringify(user.TestUrlTable.TestUrl)}</span></li>

```
it shows me undefined, in the html

Comment: since TestUrlTable is an array, you will have to loop through it to get values, can you let us know what's the output you are looking for?

Comment: I am specifically looking for 3 TesUrl values which are in TestUrlTable against specific ipadd.
it should ipadd and below this it should show list of TestUrls form API.

Comment: then you need to loop through the TestUrlTable array dynamically. I have update the answer, please check.

Comment: it is working but I need a if condition, so that it only goes under one specific ipadd.

Comment: you can add the if condition in the new for loop to check specific ipadd, please accept the answer if I resolved your question.

Comment: I need some thing like this, given below: How can I do that ???

     let temp = ``;
                    for (item of user.TestUrlTable) {
                        if (user.IpAdd == "1.10.227.44")
                        temp += `<li><i class="fa fa-mail"></i><span>${item.TestUrl}</span></li>`
                    }

Comment: can you please tell me about condition, that how can I set condition for that ??

like : if (users.push(user.IpAdd) == user.IpAdd)

Comment: I updated the answer, not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: i saw upadated code but i want auto generated values of Ipadd not "1.10.227.44" (Static one).

Comment: you can replace the static one with auto generated value, where is this auto generated value coming from?